# Titanium Studio for Android: Where does Ti.API.info() print the message?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium Studio for my first Android App. In the documentation I've come across Ti.API.info() to print any debug message. But I am not able to figure out where exactly does it print. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti.API.info() prints to the console. So, I have a function like this:

```
function OnAppResume()
{
  Ti.API.info('***---> OnAppResume');
}

$.window.addEventListener("open", function() {
    var activity = $.window.activity;
    activity.addEventListener('resume', OnAppResume);
});
```

I run it. I'll get this response in the console.

`[INFO][TiAPI   (  702)] ***---> OnAppResume`

BTW, `$.` is the new convention for Alloy MVC. Don't let it throw you off. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the DDMS console log in Eclipse. Ti.API.info() doesn't work for Android in Titanium Studio however it does log to the console. See attached image.

[image: Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

`Ti.API.info()` prints whatever inside the brackets in the console.
for example :

```
btnSubscribePush.addEventListener('click', function(){
   Ti.API.info('subscribed to push notification');//Printing your message to console
   wndSubscribe.close();//Closing the window
   Ti.API.info('Your message printing here');//Printing your message to console
});
```

You just check the console window, the message will be printed in the console as shown in the figure

[image: Ti.API.info]